# Finite approximability of graphs with finitely many automorphisms

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, graph-theory, discrete-dynamical-systems

In this question, all graphs are understood to be simple and undirected, and have countably many vertices and edges, but *not* necessarily finite.

Let $G = (V, E)$ be a graph. It is clear that any finite part of this graph can be captured by a finite graph. More precisely, if $F \subset V$ is a finite set, then there exists a finite graph $G_0 = (V_0, E_0)$ where $F \subset V_0$ and $v_1, v_2 \in F$ are adjacent in $G$ iff they are adjacent in $G_0$. Of course, one may just take $G_0$ to be subgraph of $G$ induced by $F$. This can be understood as saying graphs are finitely approximable.

However, if one wish to study the actions of groups on graphs, the correct question would be to ask whether a graph equipped with a group action is "finitely approximable", in the sense that whether: given a group $\Gamma$ acting on a graph $G = (V, E)$, a finite subset $F \subset V$, and a finite subset $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$, it is possible to construct a finite graph $G_0 = (V_0, E_0)$ equipped with an action $\alpha: \Gamma \curvearrowright G_0$ and with $F \subset V_0$, s.t. $v_1, v_2 \in F$ are adjacent in $G$ iff they are adjacent in $G_0$, and furthermore if $v \in F$, $g \in \Gamma_0$, and $gv \in F$, then $\alpha(g)v = gv$. This, obviously, is false in general. Let $\Gamma$ be an infinite simple group acting on the complete graph with vertex set $\Gamma$ by left multiplication, say.

However, I'm interested in the question where the acting group is a free group, in which case the question reduces to the issue of finite approximability of a graph equipped with finitely many automorphisms, i.e., is the following true: given a graph $G = (V, E)$, a finite subset $F \subset V$, and finitely many automorphisms $\phi_1, \cdots, \phi_n \in \mathrm{Aut}(G)$, does there exist a finite graph $G_0  = (V_0, E_0)$ with $F \subset V_0$ and finitely many automorphisms $\varphi_1, \cdots, \varphi_n \in \mathrm{Aut}(G_0)$ s.t.

1. $v_1, v_2 \in F$ are adjacent in $G$ iff they are adjacent in $G_0$;
2. If $v \in F$ and $\phi_i(v) \in F$ for some $1 \leq i \leq n$, then $\phi_i(v) = \varphi_i(v)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe this is a consequence of a 1992 theorem of Hrushovski: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01305233

Comment: (By the way, your use of the term “locally finite” conflicts with standard usage. I would call a graph “locally finite” if every vertex has finite valence.)

Comment: @HJRW Thanks for the reference! That does solve the question.

Comment: @HJRW I wasn’t aware of any standard terminology for what I was trying to define, so I just used the first name that came to my mind. You’re right though. I’ll change it to “finitely approximable”.

Comment: Yes, that’s a much better term.